# count specific characters in a list of strings python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, count, set

Hi what I am trying to do is count the specific occurrences of the characters common to each string in the list below and print out each string and how many times the common characters appear
example
barack a appears 2
barack r appears 1
when I run my code it prints that each character appears 1

```
list1 = ['barack', 'obar?ma', '?america?', 'war', 'russia?', 'mak?er'] 

common = set.intersection(*map(set,list1))

new_list = list(common)

for i in list1:
    for a in new_list:
        if a in i:
            x = new_list.count(a)
            print([i] + [a])
            print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `x = new_list.count(a)` to `x = i.count(a)`. At the moment you are counting how many `a`s in `'a'`; you want to count how many `a`s in `barack`.

The new code with this modification:

```
list1 = ['barack', 'obar?ma', '?america?', 'war', 'russia?', 'mak?er']

common = set.intersection(*map(set,list1))

new_list = list(common)

for i in list1:
    for a in new_list:
        if a in i:
            x = i.count(a)
            print([i] + [a])
            print(x)
```

prints this:

```
['barack', 'a']
2
['barack', 'r']
1
['obar?ma', 'a']
2
['obar?ma', 'r']
1
['?america?', 'a']
2
['?america?', 'r']
1
['war', 'a']
1
['war', 'r']
1
['russia?', 'a']
1
['russia?', 'r']
1
['mak?er', 'a']
1
['mak?er', 'r']
1
```